# Ajax call before close or redirect page using beforeunload()

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload

I have used $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {}) to call an ajax before the browser is closed. It actually works properly when i test on my localhost. 
Ajax call is performed perfectly for both page refresh and browser close. 
But, when i upload this to online server it seems working only for page refresh, doesn't do any thing for browser close, though in call the ajax for browser close is needed for me. 
here is my code :

```
//before close/reload browser
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {

   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
      url: "chat_online.php",
      data:{ job: 'agent_on_off', id:to_id },
      success: function(t){

      },
    });        

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with async: false in to ajax parameter. It will work.

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
      url: "chat_online.php",
      data:{ job: 'agent_on_off', id:to_id },
      async: false,
      success: function(t){

      },
    });
```

> Because on localhost you don't have a huge latency, with the server
>   you need to specify to wait for the response because it takes time
>   (few ms but still too much time for an asynchronous task)

Comment: Because on localhost you don't have a huge latence, with the server you need to specify to wait for the response because it takes time (few ms but still too much time for an async task). (Just to explain a bit more ;) )